# How to fake a method in Rails Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm trying to fake a response to a method call, but without success.

In my tests, the html rendered page will show the number of pages from. call to `<%= @pagy.pages %>` (I'm using Pagy gem), but in my test I dont need to count the pages, only to check if the page was opened.

So, the @pagy was never initialized in the test.

I need Minitest to "fake" an answer to `@pagy.pages` to always respond the number `1`:

How to do this?

Thanks!

---

After the answer from @Ahmed, this is the new code, but still not working:

```
    mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :pages, 1

    Pagy.stub :new, mock do
      create :lando, :brazilo
      get '/ameriko/brazilo'
      assert_response :success
    end
```

The view still cannot find `@pagy.pages` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Minitest Mocks in `setup` block (also can work if you put this code inside the test case block itself):

```
mock = Minitest::Mock.new
mock.expect :pages, 1

Pagy.stub :new, mock do
  # Put the code that relies on `@pagy.pages` is `1`
end
```

---

Backtrace:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `pages' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/events/_events_as_cards.haml:11:in `_app_views_events__events_as_cards_haml__846217806806687455_70361502341700'
    app/helpers/events_helper.rb:27:in `display_events_by_style'
    app/views/events/by_country.haml:20:in `_app_views_events_by_country_haml__4566190630208235120_70361501243420'
    test/controllers/events_controller_test.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <class:EventsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/events_controller_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:EventsControllerTest>'
app/views/events/_events_as_cards.haml:11:in `_app_views_events__events_as_cards_haml__846217806806687455_70361502341700'
app/helpers/events_helper.rb:27:in `display_events_by_style'
app/views/events/by_country.haml:20:in `_app_views_events_by_country_haml__4566190630208235120_70361501243420'
test/controllers/events_controller_test.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <class:EventsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/events_controller_test.rb:39:in `block in <class:EventsControllerTest>'
Finished in 1.53247s
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
I, [2019-07-15T10:00:50.384204 #47531]  INFO -- : Running locally, skipping Codacy coverage

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Still no good. MIniTest answered: ````Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `pages' for nil:NilClass````

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace? or at least the line in which the error occurred.

Comment: I addded the backtrace.
I already found a solution for my test (making a REAL @pagy instance), but I still need to understand what I was doing wrong with Mock and Stub.

Comment: This is because you need to set `@pagy` controller's instance variable before running the test spec:
`controller.instance_variable_set(:@pagy, your_mock_variable)`